# Architectural meaning of the 'scopes' in the OAuth2 process

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Two questions about OAuth2:

1) what is the architectural meaning of the 'scopes' in the OAuth2 process? I mean, which problem are they supposed to solve, why do we need them in the design?

2) for which granularity of authorization are the 'scopes' suitable? 
May they be used even for instance-specific authorization, or should they remain at the granularity-level of, say, a 'role'?

Thanks in advance for your support!
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Scope define boundaries for what you can achieve with access token. In the authorization request if you mentioned scope=openid then you will get "id_token" which contains user profile